# cant start command 'npm'' using gradlew build inside cmd

Tags: windows, gradle, cmd, npm

Currently trying to run gradlew build, but after doing a fresh install of windows on my computer it does not work anymore. any help would be appriciated

the error I am getting in command prompt is down below

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':www:node'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''

  ```
     exec {
          workingDir 'src/main/web'
          commandLine 'npm', 'install'
      }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when working on a project with both Windows and *nix. I fixed it like this...

```
if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'npm.cmd', 'install'
} else {
    commandLine 'npm', 'install'
}
```

For windows you need to use the .cmd

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I was using yarn. Gradle throws error `A problem occurred starting process 'command 'yarn''`

This works for me:

1. Go to the terminal(root directory of the project)
2. "./gradlew --stop" or "gradle stop"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/). Npm - Node Package Manager comes bundled with node. Since you have freshly installed windows so the node is not installed and the commands node/npm are not available.

Just download the installer from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) site and install it.

Also there is a better way of running node scripts and npm tasks in gradle. Check out the [node-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) for that. It is a neat wrapper over the `exec task` you are using.

Comment: Ya I already have it installed when I do npm -v it shows the version and I am able to install modules no problem thats why I am so confused

Comment: Have you tried any other exec tasks? May be an issue with gradle/permissions instead of NPM. Try running this in cmd started as "Run as Administrator"

Comment: ya still no luck gradle seems to run just fails at that task